# Table shrinks when user resizes the window. Footer pushes it's content without overlapping it

Tags: html, css

[Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCXsD.png)

I have a page with table and container at the footer. I would like to make them responsive to the browser window's size, and I don't want footer to overlap the table when I resize it. I want the table to shrink respectively.
Here is the example of code that I have so far. I need to improve it:

```
<main>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
      ...content of the table here...
 </table>
</div>
</main>
<footer>
<div class="container">This is footer</div>
</footer>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
main {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 1rem;
  }
  footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    background:orange;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume your footer has 100px height, you can wrap your table in a div set a max-height for your div:

```
#divTableWrapper{
  max-height:calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Or you can set you footer as a fixed element that always is at the bottom of body:

```
footer{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate quick response, but it didn't solve the problem. Table still doesn't shrink, and remains the same size despite the window size

Comment: You set max height for table and it not changed? Have you response the exact syntax of calc(100vh - 100px);?

Comment: Yup, it didn't changed. Table remains the same size

Comment: Fantastic Farzin, that's what I wanted to achieve! Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries! I appreciate you took time to help me, and you helped so quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

you want it?

```
<main>
<div class="container">
<div class="table table-striped">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
</main>
<footer>
<div class="container">This is footer</div>
</footer>
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/gzkjp2jk/1/

Comment: Thank you. This looks closer to what I intended to do, but footer still overlaps the table.

Comment: That's probably my fault, I wasn't clear enough of what I'm trying to achieve here: According my initial design, footer is always seen to user, no matter what size of the window is. And table size is shrinks pushed by footer.

Comment: @Trex87 can you show an example? I don't understand

Comment: I don't know how to add a picture to comments, I would show it to you. But  problem is solved. Farzin has a good example of how to fix that problem: table shrinks, and footer stays at the bottom all the time.